# Why do we use nested lambdas in scheme?

Tags: lambda, scheme, racket

I have a few lines of code in my homework:

```
(define square-a-procedure
(lambda (f) (lambda (x) (square (f x)))))
```

I don't understand why I can't write this as

```
(define square-a-procedure (lambda (f x) (square (f x))))
```

I know it is about types but I don't really get why we take parameters one by one instead of taking all of them at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both versions work by producing the same result, but one returns a partial application you can use as in higher order functions. Imagine you want to add a constant and square the elements in a list. We could user your first version with ease:

```
(define (add4 n)
  (+ n 4))

(map add-4-and-square 
     (square-a-procedure add4) 
     '(0 1 2 3))                ; ==> (16 25 36 49)
```

With your second we couldn't do that unless we wrapped it in a lambda that actually did the exact same as the first one. Very often we do partial application without thinking:

```
(map (lambda (n) (+ n 4)) '(1 2 3)) ; ==> (5 6 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

If we take two parameters at once, we are forced to take the two of them at the same point in time. So a user of our function must specify both arguments at the same time.

If we take parameters one at a time, we can get them at two different points in time. So a user of our function can specify each argument to the function separately. This is more flexible. Since Scheme has lexical scope, the inner lambda returned from the outer call "remembers" the argument used in its creation. This is what closures are, and this enables the modeling of *objects* in our code.